# C# serializable classes to xsd

Tags: c#, xsd

Is there a way of outputing xml schemas (xsd) from serialisable c# classes? I have had a look about the web but im not sure im searching for the right stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for XSD.exe  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx

Point it at a .dll and it will generate schemas for your classes.

Comment: If the dll also contains other non serializable classes will it cause problems?

Comment: I've never tried it, but I don't believe so.  Take a look at the documentation in the link, but I'm pretty sure you can even specify the specific Type you want converted if you only have one serializable type in the .dll or .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Xsd2Code works well

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: I see that goes from XSD to code.  Does it also go from code to XSD?

Comment: Sorry misread your question. Use xsd.exe as AllenG points to.