# Converting c# class to XSD file

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I have a compiled library of my old project and unfortunately I have lost the project code. Now I want to use that library code and I am using .net reflector to generate the code.
The code contains some classes which contains .xsd data and I need to convert those c# classes into .xsd files but I am not able to do so.

I tried to convert those classes into xml files but the classes have Component Model class reference which gives error.

Please suggest a way so that I can convert the classes without modifying them.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# serializable classes to xsd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709984/c-sharp-serializable-classes-to-xsd)

Comment: my class also contains some functions like fill(),update() etc. When i am converting using xsd it only converts the constructor of that class but i need everything. Please suggest.